# -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC (what is default young generation collector?)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, concurrent-mark-sweep

As far as I know we can run JVM with the next options:

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:-UseParNewGC
```

in this case we will have the **Serial (DefNew)** garbage collector for the young generation and the **Concurrent Mark Sweep** garbage collector for the old generation.

Well, can we run JVM with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` option only? I mean without any options that describes a garbage collector for the young generation. If we can do that, which garbage collector will be used for the old generation?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [this blog entry](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/10/useful-jvm-flags-part-7-cms-collector/):

> Note that with recent JVM versions `-XX:+UseParNewGC` is enabled
>   automatically when `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` is set. As a consequence,
>   if parallel young generation GC is not desired, it needs to be
>   disabled by setting `-XX:-UseParNewGC`.

For a concise summary of command line combinations, you might also be interested in [this overview](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml).